# WPF Datagrid RowValidationRules

Tags: wpf

I've a datagrid with some editable columns. If the data introduced by the user is Validated then I should calculate other columns from the same row, according with the new parameters. There is any Event after ValidationRules? A kind of ValidationSucces...Or what's the way to do that.

Thank you in advanced for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a CollectionView as Itemssource and apply to that collection a Filterproperty of type Predicate

Or you use a CollectionViewSource and handle filtering in a event.